# What's the opposite of wrinkled banknote?

Tags: word-usage, word-in-context

What's the opposite of wrinkled banknote? Can I say simply "Look at this banknote, it's **flat** like new"? Or there is a more appropriate word for this context?

Comment: Crisp is the most idiomatic in my opinion.

Comment: @BruceMurray Yeah, that would work as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer, from [usingenglish.com](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/48438-Crisp-Note):

"When paper money is new, it's referred to as being **crisp**, not all folded and wrinkled."